# Create table with merged cell using R

Tags: r

I need to create a table with some merged cells, you can consider it as a normal dataframe with 10 columns, 1:3 columns will be described on top using a merged cell, and another for 4:10 columns.

Is there any package in R for me to do? like xtable?

Comment: What format do you want to have for the output? Text? Latex? HTML? ...

Comment: @aniko, currently i am using sword to push the data directly to word, outout as WORD is perfect, if not, HTML will do also.

Comment: as you need a Word document, I think the solution with odfWeave could be perfect for you (see below), as Ms Office can open the odt format (from the 2007 version SP2).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19069468/r-remove-repeating-row-entries-in-gridextra-table

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it in Open Document Format (readable, editable in OpenOffice or Ms Office) with [odfWeave](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/odfWeave/index.html) package.

Example from documentation (see formatting.odt in [package source](http://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/odfWeave_0.7.17.tar.gz)/inst/examples):

```
library(odfWeave)
set.seed(416)
tableData <- state.x77[c(7, 38, 20, 46), c(7, 1, 8)]
states <- data.frame(type = c("Northern", "Southern"),
                     pos = c(2, 2),
                     text = "ArialCenteredItalics")

odfTable(tableData, rgroup = states)
odfTableCaption("a table using multi-cell row headers")
```