# Create merged cell table image using R

Tags: r, gridextra

Something similar like here (c#):

[GridView with merged cells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16147963/gridview-with-merged-cells)

I have tried package gridExtra and function tableGrob and grid.arrange. They create nice (e.g. png) images out of data.frames but I haven't found a way to merge cells using them.

My goal is create table images I can embed using knitr and markdown.

EDIT per Thomas K's comment:

```
p1 <- gridExtra::tableGrob(1)
nf <- matrix(c(2,3,1,1), byrow=TRUE, nrow=2)
grid.arrange(p1,p1,p1, layout_matrix = nf)
```

EDIT per bdecaf's comment:

```
require(pander)
a <- array(1:8, dim = c(2,2,2), dimnames= rep(list(letters[1:2]),3))
pander(ftable(a))
```

This gives a usable solution!

**It seems this is a duplicate of:

[R: remove repeating row entries in gridExtra table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19069468/r-remove-repeating-row-entries-in-gridextra-table?rq=1) **

Comment: Please create a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with code which shows what you have tried so far.

Comment: It really depends where the data comes from. `pander`  has a very nice output for `ftable` - though that outputs a table and not an image. But maybe you can use that for your case as well.

Comment: @bdecaf: Thanks, I will look into that. I'm perfectly okay with anything that produces nice html-table.